# How to explain the coefficient plotting as pre-trend stability testing for generalized Difference-in-Differences?

Tags: trend, difference-in-difference, generalized-did

Proving the pre-trend parallel is hard in generalized DiD.
From [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/529522/319998), Thomas Bilach suggests me a very excellent way to do so which is called "coefficient plotting"

In short, it can be achieved by running this equation

$$y_{kt} = \alpha_k + \lambda_t + \delta_{-2} d_{k,t-2} + \delta_{-1} d_{k,t-1} + \delta d_{kt} + \delta_{+1} d_{k,t+1} + \delta_{+2} d_{k,t+2} + \delta_{+\bar{3}} d_{k,t+\bar{3}} + \epsilon_{kt}$$

And then, we will see "how close the $\delta$ to 0" for pre-trend periods if I understand correctly. Some examples can be seen in the answer of @Thomas Bilach above.

My effort is that I try to mimic what @Thomas Bilach suggests, along with [adding some more covariates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/530703/319998) (independent variables). However, my result is as below, which make me feel hard in explaining regarding "how close to 0"

For example, I run such regression for two different dependent variables called $y1_{kt}$ $y2_{kt}$

The results for  is $y1_{kt}$

[image]

While dkt_4 is $d_{k,t-4}$, dkt4 is $d_{k,t+4}$
As can be seen, p-value of dkt1 is higher than 0.1, insignificant, so **whether we still plot the coefficient even it is insignificant**.

Apart from that, from the result above, is there any conclusion about the impact of laws on the dependent variable $y1_{kt}$ why the lead indicators seem to be smaller than that of lad indicators?

The result for $y2_{kt}$

[image]

How can we explain the stability trend in this case?

Answer (score 1):

A quick word with respect to the "naming" of your variables. First, the only thing separating the lead variables from the lag variables is an underscore (e.g., `_`). This makes reviewing your output very confusing. I would imagine it's difficult for you as well, especially when returning to your project after a brief hiatus. Thus, I recommend generating 'event study' variables that you can easily recognize (e.g., `lead_3`, `lead_2`, `lead_1`). The same applies to your lags (e.g., `lag_0`, `lag_1`, `lag_2`). In short, I should be able to distinguish the pre/post epoch instantaneously.

Second, what is `dkt_0` denote? Is it the last pre-treatment period or the immediate adoption period (i.e., year of change)? The `_` suggests it's a lead, however the numeric value appended to it suggests it's the first adoption year. Going forward I will assume `dkt_0` is the immediate adoption year, with `dkt1` serving as the first lag.

In the first table, the lead coefficients suggest a deviation from a common trend. The difference appears to stabilize by the second lag, but not for long. Thus, your set of coefficients for the outcome $y^{1}_{kt}$ suggest rather strong pre-trends, which casts doubt on the assumption of trend equivalence *before* policy adoption. On the other hand, the second table is bit closer to what we would expect to see in a traditional 'event study' framework. The leads suggest a stability of the trends across units in the epoch before the policy change, with a positive treatment effect emerging in the year of change. Effects persist in subsequent periods.

Lastly, ignoring the early post-treatment effects simply because they *bound zero* is very suspicious. If we don't discover punctual change, it could be that effects emerge with a lag! A discovery of a delayed effect may be of substantive interest. Conversely, dropping insignificant downstream effects may fail to show when the effects of a policy dissipate. In sum, we can't reliably exploit *when* policy effects phase-in (phase-out) if you only report a subset of highly significant post-treatment effects. Thus, never do this.

Remember, we typically plot the coefficients to show their evolution *over time*, so it's important that we preserve the chronology of effects *within* the event window—regardless of their significance. A finding of an insignificant program/policy effect may be, in and of itself, a significant discovery.