# Testing Parallel Trends Assumption

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference, trend

I am applying a difference in difference method to a time series with daily [365] observations in both the treated and control groups. To test for parallel trends I was planning on just undertaking a visual inspection of the pre-intervention trends. I am aware that commonly this is done by just looking at the raw data. However, there are 200 observations in each, which provides a messy picture. I have seen some resarch fit simple linear regressions to the pre-intervention treatment and control to provide a clearer picture of whether there are parallel trends - but am worried that this method is largely unjustified within litertaure. Does anyone have any links to papers that have used this approach?

Comment: Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548087/what-does-the-coefficients-of-lead-indicator-mean-in-parallel-trend-testing-dif/548097#548097) answer your questions?

Comment: Perfect......thanks